# Differentiable curve in Arnold's book

Tags: derivatives, curves

In the book "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" of Arnold at pag.7 it's said that the trajectory of a differentiable motion (a motion is defined previously as a curve $ x:I\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^n} $) on a plane can have the shape drawn in the figure below. In my opinion the red arrows (drawn by me: not belonging to original figure) show that in that point the motion is not differentiable because the right and the left limit are different in that point. The definition adopted by Arnold for differentiability is the classical one for curves. Where am I wrong?
[image]

Comment: There is one way in which the two red arrows are equal; if they both have length zero. Try using functions [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#An_example_function) to, for example, to make the graph of $y=|x|$ the image of a smooth curve.

Comment: You can make it work by having the particle slow down to a halt at those sharp corners, then accelerate again in a new direction. The arrows you drew have a length corresponding to speed, but the speed may be zero.

Comment: Thank you all. I get that the only way for both velocities to be equal is for them to be null. I didn't consider that trivial situation...

Comment: Can someone of you please add  his comment as answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Keep in mind you are differentiating with respect to time $t$, and that the derivative of position is *velocity*. If the point slows down coming to that sharp point $p$, has a velocity of magnitude $0$ hitting the point $p$, and then accelerates in a new direction after leaving $p$, then the right limit [just after leaving $p$] and the left limit [just before right up to arriving at $p$] of the velocity is the same--$0$.

Automobiles make $3$-point turns, while being capable of only motion that is differentiable.